# Import email leads into joomla database

Tags: email, import, joomla, export

I have 5000 registered users on another domain database, I want to import all these users in joomla database as Registered user. how to do this.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several components available to accomplish this exact task - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/users-import-a-export